# NiCr wire and water

Tags: electrochemistry, water, metal, corrosion

Suppose I'm a very impatient person and I want to heat up water by getting rid of the layer of isolation between a [NiCr wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome) and the water (e.g. skinny-dipping). The idea is that, since the wires can be heated up to >1000°, it can even be running water in high(ish) volumes. Assuming I know how to stay within electrical safety, what disadvantages are there for both the people wanting to potentially ingest water (e.g. make tea), and for the NiCr wire, in the short or long run? I'm interested in both DC and AC conditions.

Comment: @Poutnik That's true but, just because it can be heated until 1000+ deg, it doesn't mean it will be (on the electrical side, assume solid protection & co). The purpose is to get the water heated up to usable levels. Plus, the water debit will have an influence in the heat transfer. Assume the heating is "doable", I'm interested in the outcomes of such a thought at the end of the pipe (safe to drink, doesn't cause rash/diseases/etc), and on the wire (corrosion/pollution/etc if the wires will be in water all the time, ...).

Comment: I'd be happy to improve the question if there was an explanation attached to the downvote. If I had known what to correct, I would have done it since the beginning. If I haven't done it, it's probably because I am missing something. An explanation would be more than welcome.

Comment: @Poutnik Think of a pipe in which the wire is introduced and heated, while the water is running. That pipe will be left with water inside after the usage, the wires will not be conducting (only during usage). Quite literally a running-water heater but, instead of using an isolated pipe, give up the isolation, have the wire straight in the water.

Comment: @Poutnik While I appreciate the concern (and agree that accidents can happen, anytime), I'm fairly active on ee.se, so the electrical part can be considered safe: no abrupt heating, no overcurrent/overvoltage issues, all within IEC specs, controlled regulation, etc. As I said: from the electrical side, consider it solid. I'm interested in the chemical aspect of the thought.

Comment: I have deleted my prior comments.

Comment: Impatient people have no business fooling around with chemistry and electricity.

Comment: @jimchmst Oh, definitely, and presumptious people should also avoid pretending to sound smart, wouldn't you agree? I don't know what your comment has to do with my question, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main objections I can see, purely from POV of chemistry:

- Intense phase transitions or temperature gradients, together with localized mechanical shocks may lead to surface abrassion, intense corrosion or metal micro particle releases, affecting both the wire and water quality.
- Big potential gradient along the wire may lead to electrolytic activities, affecting water quality.
- Limescale will not probably have even chance to settle down on the wire, but if it does, it would strongly affect local wire temperature.
- Water may get unpleasant taste, not speaking about heavy metal traces in context of requirement for water to be drunk.

Comment: They fit quite well with what I had in mind. My reason for asking was to get a more informed version than my suspicions. I'll leave this opened for a day or two, maybe there are others who'd like to take a stab at it.

Comment: Better to get stabs here than from angry tea drinkers. :-)

Comment: Oh, I'm usually calm when I drink my tea...